# How to catch nulls and give defaults to an entire array(Transform function in Dataweave)?

Tags: function, null, dataweave

I used an elseif function to prevent my API from failing due to `null` values.

```
"4435555555"
else if ( payload.ship_address.phone as String != "")
payload.ship_address.phone
else
"4435555555"
var cust_name = if ( payload.ship_address.name == null)
"Client Customer"
else if (payload.ship_address.name as String == "")
"Client Customer"
else
payload.ship_address.name
```

I know I could do this for every value by doing a ton of functions but is there a way to do this for the entire array in one function?

```
var telephoneNumber = if ( payload.ship_address.phone == null)
"4435555555"
else if ( payload.ship_address.phone as String != "")
payload.ship_address.phone
else
"4435555555"
var cust_name = if ( payload.ship_address.name == null)
"Client Customer"
else if (payload.ship_address.name as String == "")
"Client Customer"
else
payload.ship_address.name
---
{
    order: {
        client_identifier: payload.po,
        brand: "CLIENT_BRAND",
        shipping_method: shippingMethod default "Standard",
        price_cents: floor (payload.total as Number * 100),
        channel: "rts_dropship",
        tax_cents: 0,
        shipping_cost_cents: 0,
        shipping_tax_cents: 0,
        billing_address: {
            name: cust_name default "Client Customer",
            telephone_number: telephoneNumber,
            street: payload.ship_address.line1,
            city: payload.ship_address.city,
            state: payload.ship_address.state,
            zip_code: payload.ship_address.postal_code,
            country: payload.ship_address.country,
            street2: payload.ship_address.line2,
            company: payload.ship_address.company
        },
        shipping_address: {
            name: cust_name default "Client Customer",
            telephone_number: telephoneNumber,
            street: payload.ship_address.line1,
            city: payload.ship_address.city,
            state: payload.ship_address.state,
            zip_code: payload.ship_address.postal_code,
            country: payload.ship_address.country,
            street2: payload.ship_address.line2,
            company: payload.ship_address.company
        },
        order_items: payload.items map ( item , indexOfItem ) -> {
            client_identifier: item.id,
            sku: item.quants.vpc[0],
            condition: "N",
            quantity: item.quants.quantity[0] as Number,
            price_cents: floor ((item.unit_cost as Number default 0) * 100),
            tax_cents: 0,
            shipping_cost_cents: 0,
            shipping_tax_cents: 0,
            brand: item.brand_name,
            comments: payload.vendor_notes default ""
        },
        packing_slip_identifier: payload.items.quants[0].ositems[0].order_channel_refnum[0]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Helper function using the `isEmpty` function and use it like you use `default` keyword.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun ifEmptyThen(string, defaultValue) = 
    if(isEmpty(string)) defaultValue
    else string
---
{
    nonEmptyValue: "nonEmpty" ifEmptyThen "defaultForNonEmpty",
    blankString: "" ifEmptyThen "defaultForBlankString",
    nullValue: null ifEmptyThen "defaultForNull"
}
```

The output of this will look like:

```json
{
  "nonEmptyValue": "nonEmpty",
  "blankString": "defaultForBlankString",
  "nullValue": "defaultForNull"
}
```

Comment: You can apply this ifEmptyThen function to the entire object in one shot by using the mapObject function, and I think this answer will be complete.